# Site migration on Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, migration, visual-composer

I ask you for advice.
I am completely redoing a wp, containing about 250-300 pages with the same style (they are trips).
At the time, each page created had been duplicated a default page and then modified the content, so the pages are 99% similar in setting.

Now with the new wp, I have a theme with a Visual composer (wpbakery page builder) and I created a template to use.
I would like to know if you have any ideas or advice on how to export, process and import all those pages into the new composer.

Obviously the new site, for this type of page (trip) has a similar structure, so maybe what used to be inside a plugin (eg Tabby Responsive Tabs), now is in a composer block.

I hope I explained myself.

Thank you very much and good evening

Answer (score 0):

have you license version of visual composer?

Comment: no, currently not, because the composer was already in the theme and I don't need to buy a license for updates, but if there is a plugin or something else that can help me I can buy it!

Comment: You need to backup full site with akeeba backup plugin and also you need to create a database backup so you easily transfer on your staging site.

Comment: And i attached one another option for you. Please check below URL:
https://prnt.sc/q47lyq

Comment: I don t need transfer the site, but export and bulk edit of trips ‘s pages.

Comment: Please check my second comment. you need to all pages save into the templates. after you can export that without any plugin. you can use wordpress export option.

Comment: Hi, 
I checked the link you sent me, but I have to do the opposite.

I don't have to export a VC template, but I have to export pages (trips, html) to a template in VC.